# Asginar colores según condicionales JavaFX

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, condiciones

Buenas tardes a todos!

Al grano!

Tengo el siguiente codigo en `JavaFX` en el cual especifico asignarle colores y un texto a un label y a un boton segun el valor que se traiga de la base de datos en el campo `kmRestPanel.getText()` en cual lo convierto a Integer para cuestion de evaluar pero a la hora que se dispara la accion el resultado es este:

[image: Resultado]

Aqui esta el codigo:

```
 //ALERTAS POR KM
        int txt_kmrecototal = Integer.parseInt(kmRestPanel.getText());
        if (txt_kmrecototal > 4000) {
            btn_alertaPanel.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#00ff46;");
            lb_DescripAlertPane.setText("NORMAL");
            lb_AlertaKmRest.setText(plac.getKmRestante(conexion.getConnection()));
        } else if (txt_kmrecototal <= 4000 || txt_kmrecototal >= 3000 ) {
            btn_alertaPanel.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#00ff46;");
            lb_DescripAlertPane.setText("NORMAL");
            lb_AlertaKmRest.setText(plac.getKmRestante(conexion.getConnection()));
        } else if (txt_kmrecototal <= 3000 || txt_kmrecototal >= 2000 ) {
            btn_alertaPanel.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#fff000;");
            lb_DescripAlertPane.setText("ADVERTENCIA");
            lb_AlertaKmRest.setText(plac.getKmRestante(conexion.getConnection()));
        } else if (txt_kmrecototal <= 2000 || txt_kmrecototal >= 1000 ) {
            btn_alertaPanel.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#fff000;");
            lb_DescripAlertPane.setText("ADVERTENCIA");
            lb_AlertaKmRest.setText(plac.getKmRestante(conexion.getConnection()));
        } else if (txt_kmrecototal <= 1000 ) {
            btn_alertaPanel.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#ff0000;");
            lb_DescripAlertPane.setText("PELIGRO");
            lb_AlertaKmRest.setText(plac.getKmRestante(conexion.getConnection()));

        }
        //FIN ALERTAS POR KM
```

Bueno si ven mi valor traido es 1000 lo que segun mi codigo deberia aparecer es "PELIGRO" y el color rojo pero no lo logro.

Si hay algun error o estoy haciendo algo mal porfa agradesco su ayuda!
Saludos!!

Comment: Hola @Riddick para editar y agregar más información a tu pregunta es la opción [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/113547/edit), saludos!

Comment: Tú tienes dos comparaciones que evalúan si es igual a `1000`, por ejemplo: `} else if (txt_kmrecototal <= 2000 || txt_kmrecototal >= 1000 ) {` y lo mismo ocurre con otros valores. Debes revisar tus ciclos de comparaciones.

Answer (score 0):

Definitivamente necesitas re-estructurar todo esto; Con 1000 entra en el segundo bloque de condiciones, porque se cumple la de `kmrecototal <= 4000`. Ire también al grano aconsejando:

```
if( txt_mkrecototal <= 1000 ) {
  // Status Peligro
} else if( txt_mkrecototal <= 3000 ) {
  // Status Advertencia
} else {
  // Status Normal
}
```

Comment: Gracias probando !

Comment: Buena respuesta. Además puedes crear dos variables para guardar el mensaje y el estilo, darle valores según la condición que se cumpla y hacer los set al final del if. Así te ahorrarás al menos 4 líneas de código y escribirás un programa más fácil de leer y mantener. Lo mismo esta línea: `lb_AlertaKmRest.setText(plac.getKmRestante(conexion.getConnection()));` no tendría por qué estar repetida una y otra vez en cada if.

Comment: Cierto amigo tambien pense eso, noté que repito mucho codigo si puedes darme una mano en como hacer eso seria de ayuda Gracias